# Setting dynamic yaxis labels ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set a dynamic yaxis label that adjusts to either millions or thousands. Because the data is constantly changing each time pulled in, I can't just hardcode it.

I couldn't find anything on the subject so I was thinking something like an `if_else` statement would work, but I'm getting an error.

Reprex is using `ChickWeight` dataset. Here I was trying to get it scale to million since it meets the minimum threshold, but if it didn't to switch to thousand. Thinking maybe I need to include min and max. Would an `if_else` even be the right approach? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
df <- ChickWeight

lumpy <- (ChickWeight$weight * 10000)

df %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = `Time`, y = lumpy)) +
  if_else(lumpy >= 1000000,
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, 
                     labels =  ~scales::comma(., scale = 1/1000000, suffix = "M", accuracy = 1)),
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, 
                     labels =  ~scales::comma(., scale = 1/100000, suffix = "K", accuracy = 1)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use `labels = scales::label_number(scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale())` to allow it to determine (based on observed data) which to use. (No `if_else` required.)

```r
df <- ChickWeight
lumpy <- (ChickWeight$weight * 10)
df %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = `Time`, y = lumpy)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, labels = scales::label_number(scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale()))
```

[image: y-axis scale uses "K" in labels]

Same plot code, but `weight` is a bit larger:

```r
df <- ChickWeight
lumpy <- (ChickWeight$weight * 10000) # BIGGER
df %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = `Time`, y = lumpy)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, labels = scales::label_number(scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale()))
```

[image: y-axis scale uses "M" in labels]

Comment: Learned something new here. Great answer, deserves more upvoted.

Comment: @AllanCameron ... my secret: I didn't know this before now, _this_ is how I learn things in R/python: by trying things when somebody asks. The biggest thing I think I bring to the game is having a good idea where to look and what keywords/topics to look for. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans - that's my secret too ;)